# ERROR: column "num" does not exist Where: PL/pgSQL function bulletin_abbrege(integer) line 3 at SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bulletin_abbrege(in num INTEGER)
language plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bulletin_abrege AS
SELECT concat(substring(candidat_nom,1,1),substring(candidat_prenom,1,1)) as initiales,parti_abv as abbrevation_parti,compte_nom as compte_nom
FROM candidat INNER JOIN parti ON candidat.parti_id=parti.parti_id INNER JOIN compte ON candidat.compte_id=compte.compte_id
WHERE candidat.compte_id = num;
END;
$$;
```

[42703] ERROR: column "num" does not exist Where: PL/pgSQL function bulletin_abbrege(integer) line 3 at SQL statement

I don't understand why it says the column does not exist when it is a value passed in arguments in the function?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is a PROCEDURE not a FUNCTION
2. From Execute query:

> Non-optimizable SQL commands (also called utility commands) are not capable of accepting query parameters. So automatic substitution of PL/pgSQL variables does not work in such commands. To include non-constant text in a utility command executed from PL/pgSQL, you must build the utility command as a string and then EXECUTE it, as discussed in Section 43.5.4.

Try something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE bulletin_abbrege(in num INTEGER)
language plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bulletin_abrege AS
SELECT concat(substring(candidat_nom,1,1),substring(candidat_prenom,1,1)) as initiales,parti_abv as abbrevation_parti,compte_nom as compte_nom
FROM candidat INNER JOIN parti ON candidat.parti_id=parti.parti_id INNER JOIN compte ON candidat.compte_id=compte.compte_id
WHERE candidat.compte_id = %L', num);
END;
$$;
```

Per [Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and [Format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).